# Difference between creating a method with no parameter and a string parameter?

Tags: java

I am just wondering what the difference would be in creating a method with no parameter vs one with a String parameter. To my understanding, the method with no defined parameter can be called anywhere in the program where as the one with the String parameter only works for the String (unsure)?  For example

```
public static void exampleOne(){
}
```

vs

```
public static void exampleOne(String x){
}
```

Comment: the deference is that when you invoke the methods `exampleOne` takes no argument  whereas `exampleOn` does not.

Comment: Please have a look at polymorphism. Though all opp languages doesn't support polymorphism like Dart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add some code to these methods, the terminologie will pop up clearly =)

```
public static void exampleOne(){
    System.out.println("hello World");
}
```

and

```
public static void exampleTwo(String x){
    System.out.println("hello World, "+x);
}
```

then you can **parametrize** the outcome from `exampleTwo` by providing the String x.

> `exampleOne(); //will print Hello World`
>
> `exampleTwo("BipoN"); //will print Hello World BipoN`

Comment: So in my understanding, it makes String x available to be used in that method correct? Otherwise String x would not be found since its apart of a different class?

Answer (score 1):

Given example is overloaded function falls under OOPS concept.

```
public class Booking{
    public void flightTicket(){
    return "ticket";
    }

    public void flightTicket(String meal){
    return "ticket with "+meal;
    }
}
```

Above example describe for booking flight ticket. If you want to just book the flight ticket first function will be called while with meal another will.

How to call those functions

```
Booking booking = new Booking();
booking.flightTicket(); //will print ticket
booking.flightTicket("Veg"); // will print ticket with Veg
```

Comment: In this case, would String meal be declared in the main method or within the second method as: meal = "Veg";   ?  Or is is declared within booking.flightTicket("**Veg**");

Comment: @BipoN This is pass by value. by saying booking.flightTicket("Veg"); Code is looking for a method which can accept String type, in this case string is "veg" it can be anything. No in case you don't define method which accept String booking.flightTicket("Veg") will throw compile time error.

Answer (score 1):

It's based on what requirement you have. Like what are the different types of variables that you would like to have single definitions! For example, for a single method, you may have different types of business logic based on argument type or a number of arguments to do. This concept is called Method overloading.

The best example I found is inbuild Java class.

```
System.out.println(int x);
System.out.println(boolean x);
System.out.println(String x);
```

You can see the inbuild implementation of these methods.